# Can a Transfinite set of any given size possess a top element?

Tags: order-theory

Can an infinite set have a Top element? Can a set of any given transfinite Cardinality possess a Top element? Are there any examples of known sets that have top elements and are more than finite? I am pretty certain that this is possible but I have only heard finite cases talked about.

Comment: Yes, closed unit interval has a top element.

Comment: Thank you. You revealed that as stated that was a fairly dumb question, I don't know why I didn't think of that. What about in general is a true for a transfinite set of any given cardinality?

Comment: It doesn't actually make any sense to ask if "any infinite set has a top element," since sets don't intrinsically have an ordering of their elements. As Asaf's answer says, under a certain assumption any infinite set can be *given an ordering* that has a top element. You can also generally give the same sets an alternative ordering that doesn't have a top element.

Comment: My wording was a little weird but I understand that, I was asking if for all sizes of sets "any cardinality"  cases of sets with top elements existed. Thank you for the  clarification.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Every set can be linearly ordered, assuming the axiom of choice, and given any linear order $(X,\leq)$, we can pick one $x\in X$ and define $\leq_x$ which is $\leq$ on $X\setminus\{x\}$, and $y\leq_x x$ for all $y\in X$.

Since assuming choice gives you that every set can also be well-ordered, you can require that $\leq$ (and consequently $\leq_x$) is a well-order as well, which means that every non-empty set has a minimum too.

Another approach here is a model theoretic approach: let $T$ be the theory in the language of $\leq$ stating that $\leq$ is a linear ordering with a maximum. It is certainly consistent, and it has models of every finite size, therefore, by the compactness theorem, it has an infinite model, and therefore, by the Löwenheim–Skolem theorem, an infinite model of any given size.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. Would give rep if I could.

Comment: You're welcome.